# CUSTOM DELIMITER : SQL Server - CSV Export using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, csv, export, delimiter

```
Begin
Declare @registration_no int = 101
declare @bcp varchar(8000)

set @bcp = 'sqlcmd -s, -W -Q "set nocount on; SELECT * FROM [Student_Management].[dbo].[Student] WHERE registration_no= '+ cast(@registration_no as nvarchar(10))+' " | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "d:\student.csv"'    

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp
end
```

The above statements export the table data as CSV correctly, but instead of comma-separated values, **I want pipe(|) separated output**. Where can I mention a custom delimiter(|)

Edit:

```
Begin
Declare @registration_no int = 101
declare @bcp varchar(8000)


set @bcp ='sqlcmd -s"|"-W -Q "set nocount on; SELECT * FROM [Student_Management].[dbo].[Student] WHERE registration_no= '+ cast(@registration_no as nvarchar(10))+' " | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "d:\student.csv"'    
    

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp

END
```

Comment: Larnu you are right, please ignore the variable name

Comment: The document says this

-s col_separator
Specifies the column-separator character. The default is a blank space. This option sets the sqlcmd scripting variable SQLCMDCOLSEP. To use characters that have special meaning to the operating system such as the ampersand (&), or semicolon (;), enclose the character in quotation marks ("). The column separator can be any 8-bit character.

Comment: Can you help how to do I mention 
Example -s'|'

When I do this I get : Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the '|' operator.

Comment: Still getting 
The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the "|" operator.

Comment: It worked in further attempts but giving too much whitespace, between values. Can you please suggest something ?

Comment: Resolved : moved -w before -s

Comment: @Larnu : Thank You Very much, your help is appreciated. 
Thanks for quickly responding

Comment: It finally worked!!

Comment: I'm sorry @Larnu

Answer (score 0):

```
Begin
Declare @registration_no int = 101
declare @cmd varchar(8000)

set @cmd='sqlcmd -W -s"|", -Q "set nocount on; SELECT * FROM [Student_Management].[dbo].[Student] WHERE registration_no= '+ cast(@registration_no as nvarchar(10))+' " | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "d:\student.csv"'   

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp

END
```